# How can I run a postgresql query over array of strings?

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a script which will take all tables from my schema and perform some actions on them. The tables that will be taken have same prefix and different suffix. Now, what I want to do is to declare an array at the beginning of the script, the array will contain all regex for all tables that I need, for example:

```
base_tables varchar[2] := ARRAY['table_name_format_2%',
                            'another_format_3%'];
```

Using this array, I would like to go through all the tables in my schema and take only those that match the name pattern in the array.
I tried to do this as such:

```
FOR table_item IN
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_name LIKE IN base_tables
    LOOP 
        ---- Some code goes here -----
    END LOOP;
```

The error I get is :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IN"

What is the correct way to compare each table name, to the names in my array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d3472efce162375f83c7751b61493d2c)

To get a match for an array element you have to use:

```
-- general case
WHERE element = ANY(ARRAY['elem1', 'elem2'])

-- your case
WHERE table_name = ANY(base_tables)
```

---

If you want to achieve a `LIKE` eehrm... like operation you'll need another way:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables t
JOIN (SELECT unnest(base_tables) as name) bt
ON t.table_name LIKE bt.name
```

Joining `tables` against an unnested `base_tables` array (`unnest` expands an array to one row for each element). You can join with the `LIKE` operator.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ec9b1bcb43ebc275619dcd050c95d930)

Comment: When I use ANY, does it look for exact match in the array, or does it check if the table name matches the regex pattern in the array? I need the latter option to happen.

* I tried it now, and it seems that it looks for exact match and not a match by regex pattern.

Comment: Expanded the answer